# Deformation theory over F_p

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, deformation-theory

Lurie proves that formal $E_\infty$ moduli problems over a field $k$ are equivalent to augmented $E_\infty$-algebras.

Is there a reasonably small model for this when $k = \mathbb{F}_p$?

Or maybe we could have a similar, but different, statement where we start with moduli problems over [commutative algebras with additional Steenrod operations], and on the output we get a suitably modified category of dg Lie algebras?